# Google Studio - How to change the display of dates in line chart?

Tags: looker-studio

I am using Google Data Studio and have a date field that comes in as "2022-05-23".

But in the charts themselves they always get displayed as May 23, 2022.
How does one tell google to stick to something like "2022-05-23" or does google insist on spelling out the Month to avoid any confusion?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated field that format the date column as string, using the function [`FORMAT_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9730334?hl=en):

```
FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d", my_date_column)
```